# When $A$ is a $n \times n $ Jordan block in $M_n(F)$, what is the Jordan form of $A^m$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $F$ be a field ( in special case let $F=\mathbb C$). Assume that $A$  be a  $n \times n $ Jordan block in $M_n(F)$. When $m$ is a natural number,  what is the Jordan form of $A^m$?

Comment: Try calculating $A^m$ for some small value of $m,n$, and you should see a pattern. By that I mean, set $n$ to, say, $4$, and calculate $A^m$ for $m=1,2,3,4$. Notice anything?

Comment: is it true that the jordan form of  $A^m$ is a jordan block $n \times n$?

Comment: Did you calculate $A^2$ for at least one $4\times 4$ matrix?

Comment: In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form, you can find $A^m$ for a jordan block.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a jordan block.

Comment: My quastion is  "what is the Jordan form of  $A^m $"?

Comment: Assume that $A$ be $2 \times 2$ jordan block such that $a_{11}=1, a_{12}=1, a_{21}=0, a_{22}=1$, then for any $m$, assume that $A^m=[b_{ij}]$. It is clear that  $b_{11}=1, b_{12}=m, b_{21}=0, b_{22}=1$, what is the jordan form of $A^m$?

Comment: I said the jordan form of $A^m$ is $0$? Really? Where did I say that?

Comment: the last comment  is not for you, previous comment  is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $J_n(\lambda)$ the Jordan block of size $n$ for an eigenvalue $\lambda$. Hence $A=J_n(\lambda)$ for some $\lambda$.

**(I)** When $A$ is not nilpotent and the field has characteristic zero, the Jordan form of $A^m$ is just $J_n(\lambda^m)$. That is, the Jordan form itself is a single Jordan block of size $n$.

**(II)** When $A$ is not nilpotent and the field has finite characteristic, things get messier. For instance, over $GF(2)$, consider the case where $n=3,m=2$ and
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ &1&1\\ &&1},\quad A^m=A^2=\pmatrix{1&0&1\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1}
\sim \pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1\\ &&1}.
$$
So, the $A^m$ in this case has Jordan blocks of sizes smaller than $n$. The general case depends on $n,m$, the actual value of the eigenvalue as well as the characteristic of the field. It looks complicated and I'm not sure if there is an easy answer.

**(III)** When $A$ is nilpotent, there are two possibilities:

1. $1\le m<n$. Then $T=A^m$ is the matrix whose only nonzero entries are a line of ones extended from the $(1,m+1)$-th entry southeastward. Hence the only nontrivial cyclic subspace of $T$ is subspace spanned by the subset $\{e_n,e_{n-1},e_{n-2},\ldots,e_m\}$ of standard basis. As the dimension of this cyclic subspace is $(n+1-m)$, the Jordan form of $T$ is $J_{n+1-m}(0)\oplus0_{(m-1)\times(m-1)}$.
2. $m\ge n$. Then $T=A^m=0$ and the Jordan form of $T$ is just itself, the zero matrix.

Comment: is there any reference for first case.? "When $A$ is not nilpotent," is it true for any arbitrary field?

Comment: @RezaFallah-Moghaddam It's so trivial that I don't think anyone would state it as a lemma in a reference book. Clearly all eigenvalues of $T=A^m$ are equal to $\lambda^m$. And the index of nilpotency of $N=T-\lambda^m I$ is $n$ (that is, $N^n=0$ but $N^{n-1}\ne0$). So the largest Jordan block of $T$ has size $n$, i.e. the Jordan form of $T$ consists only of a single Jordan block.

Comment: @RezaFallah-Moghaddam Now come to think of it, the answer really isn't trivial if the field has finite characteristic. I'll see think about it when I have time.